# In a sound theory, $T$, for a Godel sentence $G_{T}$ is $\neg G_{T}$ being false a true or false statement

Tags: logic

Smith's "Intro to Godel's Theorems," defines $T$ as a sound theory as everything $T$ proves must be true.

He then mentions a Godel sentence $G_{T}$ which I would characterize as $T\vdash (G_{T}\leftrightarrow\neg\square G_{T})$.

"So $G_{T}$ is true if and only if $T$ can't prove it....Hence if $T$ is sound, $G_{T}$ is unprovable in $T$. Which makes $G_{T}$ true."

I understand the above and that it follows from $T\vdash (G_{T}\leftrightarrow\neg\square G_{T})$.

Now comes my question:

He goes on to say, "Hence $\neg G_{T}$ is false. And so that too can't be proved by $T$, since $T$ only proves truths."

But in this instance, isn't $\neg G_{T}$ being false a truth?

Or, what probably is incorrect: $T\vdash(\neg G_{T}\leftrightarrow \square G_{T})$, and since I started with $G_{T}$ is true, then in this case $\neg G_{T}$ is true.

Thanks

Comment: isn't $¬G_T$ being false a truth? Yes, i.e. $¬¬G_T$ is true. The meta-theory is "classic" and thus double negation holds.

Comment: You've misunderstood "And so that too". Here "that" refers to $\neg G_T$, not to "$\neg G_T$ is false".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$T$ does indeed prove $\neg G_T\iff\Box G_T$. However, I'm not sure how you get from this to the claim in your last sentence that $\neg G_T$ is true.

I think the key is the following: we're assuming that $T$ only proves true statements, but we're not assuming that $T$ proves *all* true statements. $G_T$ is true, and *if* $T$ proved $G_T$ then $G_T$ would be false, but we can't go from "$G_T$ is true" to "$T$ proves $G_T$" (in fact, that's the whole point of $G_T$).

So I think the issue is really linguistic here: that "$T$ only proves truths" is easy to misread as "the things $T$ proves are the truths."

Answer (score 2):

You understood that $G_T$ is true. Well, then it follows that $\neg G_T$ is false.

Of course, that also means that the statement "$\neg G_T$ is false" is a true statement .. but we're not really interested in *that* statement here.

Likewise, if we say that $A$ is true, then $\neg A$ is false. And again, it would then also be true that "$\neg A$ is false", but that does not make $\neg A$ true. In fact, if it is true that "$\neg A$ is false", then clearly $\neg A$ is false, not true.

We would only have that $\neg A$ is true if "$\neg A$ is false" is false.

Comment: The second-to-last sentence of this answer seems to be a typo: you've written "$True(False(\neg A))$ implies $True(\neg A)$," that is "$A\implies\neg A$." (The last sentence, though, is correct.) @Andrew The point of this answer is just that "False" and "$\neg$" are the same thing, and double negation cancels; e.g. "(($A$ is false) is false) is false" is just "$\neg\neg\neg A$," which simplifies to "$\neg A$," which is true iff $A$ is false.

Comment: @Andrew Both of the claims mentioned above can be unpacked. "False$(x)$=$\neg(x)$ and True$(x)$=$x$" is the least objectionable (although [even it is nontrivial](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/truth-deflationary/)), and of course double negation cancellation is not intuitionistically true. But everything here is taking place in classical logic, which makes things quite simple.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Ha ha, I confused myself :) Too many negations!